# Does where clause run first and then the analytical function or how does the execution takes place in below query specifically?

Tags: sql, where-clause, greatest-n-per-group, window-functions

```
WITH conversions AS (
SELECT 
    *
FROM attribution a JOIN user_sessions u ON a.session_id = u.session_id
WHERE conversion = TRUE)

SELECT 
       user_id,
       **ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY user_id ORDER BY created_at END) AS rnk,**
       channel
FROM attribution a JOIN user_sessions u ON a.session_id = u.session_id
WHERE user_id IN (SELECT DISTINCT user_id FROM conversions) 
**AND rnk = 1**
```

My confusion lies in the following two points:
1 - If Where clause is running first and we have only selective User_ids to run row_number() analytical function over. Then how can we use rnk = 1 here
2 - If we have row_number() running first then it means it is ranking each user_id irrespective of the WHERE clause. Is this correct?

Which statement makes more sense from the above two?

Answer (score 1):

Conceptually, the window functions only sees rows that remain *after* the filtering in the `where` clause. A corollary is that you can't use a window function in the `where` clause, as you are attempting here (that's a syntax error).

I don't see at all the point for the `with` clause in your code. Presumably, the query you want is:

```
select *
from (
    select user_id, channel,
        row_number() over(partition by user_id order by created_at) rn
    from attribution a
    inner join user_sessions u on u.session_id = u.session_id
    where conversion = true
) t
where rn = 1
```

I would highly recommend prefixing each and every column in the query with he alias of the table it belongs to, so the query is unambiguous about the underlying data structure.

Comment: Thank you @GMB for a quick reply. It makes sense not to use with clause here. I just wanted to make sure that my understanding is correct and the above query is wrong when we use rnk in the Where clause.Thanks